# Scrape Data From A HTML Table

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am really struggling in trying to pull some data of a web table. I have scraped web data in the past but never from a table and can not work it out

I have tried several variations but nothing seems to work, I have channged the class several times and the child node number to reflect each items, however I can not extract anything from the table

Q) Can someone advise on the table class and how to extract from a `td`

I have read several posts on this forum and other forums on scraping from a table, however none helped, hence the post

```
  ''''Data 1
        On Error Resume Next
        If doc.getElementsByClassName("content")(0).getElementsByTagName("td").Children(0) Is Nothing Then
            wsSheet.Cells(StartRow + myCounter, 1).Value = "-"
        Else
         On Error Resume Next
            wsSheet.Cells(StartRow + myCounter, 1).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("content")(0).getElementsByTagName("td").Children(0).innerText
        End If
```

I have tried the following Variations

```
doc.getElementsByClassName("content")(0)
```

```
doc.getElementsByClassName("content")(0)).Children(0)
```

```
doc.getElementsByClassName("content")(0).getElementsByTagName("th").getElementsByTagName("td").Children(0)
```

```
doc.getElementsByClassName("content")(0).getElementsByTagName("td").Children(0)
```

This is an image of the html, I tried to put in the html code, but could not get it to look right

[image: HTML IMAGE]

As always thanks in advance

Comment: `ie.document.querySelector(".contact-table").outerHTML` to copy to clipboard or loop rows and columns of `ie.document.querySelector(".contact-table")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First an advice: Split those statements into pieces and save the result into intermediate variables.

Then an observation: The `<td>`-tags have no children, so `children(0)` will return `Nothing` (the `<th>` on that page has a child, the `<span>`-tag) . You probably want to read the content of the cell, you can do this with the property `InnerHtml`.

Remove the `On Error Resume Next`-statement. As long as you are developing your routine, let the code run into errors so you can easily debug and see the place where the code fails. And once you are ready, it's better to check for errors by yourself.

Not sure if the following fits, but it should give you the idea:

```
' Fetch the "Content"-DIV
Dim content As Object
Set content = HtmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("content")(0)

' Fetch the first table with that div
Dim table As Object
Set table = content.getElementsByTagName("table")(0)

' Loop over all <td>-Tags and print the content
Dim td As Object
For Each td In table.getElementsByTagName("td")
    Debug.Print td.innerHTML
    If td.Children.Length > 0 Then
        ' If <td> has children, fetch the first child and show the content
        Dim child As Object
        Set child = td.Children(0)
        Debug.Print " We found a child: " & child.tagName, child.innerHTML
    End If
Next
```

When you debug the code, remember to use the "Locals Window" of the VBA (View->Locals Window). There you can inspect all the details of the objects.